How to draw shapes of the same size in a perspective view using GLSL?
How to make two triangles the same size?
Thanks!

import bpy
import gpu
from mathutils import Vector
from gpu_extras.batch import batch_for_shader
import numpy as np
from bpy_extras import view3d_utils

if hasattr(bpy, 'test_handler'):
    try:
        bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_remove(bpy.test_handler, 'WINDOW')
    except: pass

def get_view_regions(context):
    screen = context.screen
    view_region = None
    view_region_3d = None
    for a in screen.areas:
       if a.type == "VIEW_3D":
            view_region_3d = a.spaces[0].region_3d
            for reg in a.regions[:]:
                if reg.type == "WINDOW":
                    view_region = reg
                    break
            break
    return view_region, view_region_3d
    
region, rv3d = get_view_regions(bpy.context)

vertex_shader = '''
    in vec2  pos;      
    in vec3  offset;
    in vec4  color;
        
    uniform mat4  matrix_p;
    uniform vec2  screen_size;
    uniform float scale;
    
    out vec4 fcolor;    

    void main()
    {        
        float s = scale;
        if (s < 5.0f) s = 5.0f;
        vec4 loc = vec4(s * pos * 2.0 / screen_size, 0, 0);
        gl_Position = loc + matrix_p * vec4(offset, 1.0);
        fcolor = color;
    }
'''

fragment_shader = '''
    in vec4  fcolor;
    out vec4 fragColor;

    void main()
    {
        fragColor = blender_srgb_to_framebuffer_space(fcolor);
    }
'''

def batch_polygons(locs, segments, polygon_co):
    positions = np.array(locs)
    len_pos = len(positions)

    indices = []
    for i in range(len_pos):
        for j in range(1, segments - 1):
            indices.append([i*segments, i*segments + j, i*segments + j + 1])

    vertices = np.tile(polygon_co, (len_pos, 1))
    offsets = np.repeat(positions, segments, axis=0)

    return vertices.tolist(), offsets.tolist(), indices

shader = gpu.types.GPUShader(vertex_shader, fragment_shader)

segments = 3

a = 50
polygon_co = [
    [0, a],
    [a, -a],
    [-a, -a]
]

pos0 = [(0,0,0), (1,1,1)]
color0 = [(1,0,0,1), (1,1,0,1)]
color = [c for c in color0 for _ in range(segments)]

coords, offsets, indices = batch_polygons(pos0, segments, polygon_co)

batch = batch_for_shader(shader, 'TRIS',
            {"pos": coords, "offset": offsets, "color": color}, indices=indices)


def draw():
    screen_size = Vector((region.width, region.height))
    shader.uniform_float("matrix_p", rv3d.perspective_matrix)
    shader.uniform_float("screen_size", screen_size)
    if rv3d.view_perspective == "ORTHO":
        shader.uniform_float("scale",  1 )
    else:
        shader.uniform_float("scale", rv3d.view_distance )
    batch.draw(shader)

bpy.test_handler = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw, (), 'WINDOW', 'POST_VIEW')


Please use the python and/or scripting tags when asking about scripting.

If you want to draw them at the same scale and avoid some headaches, you should draw them in screen space rather than world space : https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy_extras.object_utils.html#bpy_extras.object_utils.world_to_camera_view

@Gorgious I don't think it's advisable to do it that way because 2D drawing will prevent the points from synchronizing in real time when the view is rotated.

Yes they can if you use https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy_extras.object_utils.html#bpy_extras.object_utils.world_to_camera_view

@Gorgious I don't understand the usage of world_to_camera_view(scene, obj, coord). I am not using a camera, and there is no camera object.
